# pyqt threading, appropriate pattern?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I working on a gui application which plots real time data as it comes in. There is a main class which is a plot window. The window shows the plot of the data itself as well as a number of buttons, checkboxes, textboxes, etc. that a user can interact with to modify the plot output. All of these widgets configure the "settings" for the plot. The plotting of new data itself is resource intensive. The loading and plotting of the data may take around a second. I want the user to be able to modify the settings in the GUI without worrying about the lag of loading and plotting so I want to execute the loading and plotting in a separate thread.

I've come up with, what seems to me, to be a weird way to accomplish this but which works. It is something like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal


class PlotWorker(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, plotwindow):
        self.plotwindow = plotwindow
        self.plot_thread = QThread()
        self.plot_thread.start()
        self.moveToThread(self.plot_thread)
    
    def worker_update:
        self.plotwindow.updating = True
        self.plotwindow.plot()
        self.plotwindow.updating = False


class PlotWindow(Ui_PlotWindow, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    update_signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.settings = self.settings_lineEdit.text()
        self.worker = PlotWorker(self)
        self.update_signal.connect(self.worker.worker_update)
        self.update_settings_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.update_settings)
        self.updating = False
        self.refresh_timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.refresh_timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.update_settings()
        self.plot()
        self.refresh_time.start(1)


    def update_setting(self):
        self.settings = self.settings_lineEdit.text()
 
    def update(self)
        if self.updating:
            print('Already updating, cannot update until previous update complete')
        elif not self.updating:
            self.update_signal.emit()

    def plot(self):
        # Plot the data, slow. Uses self.settings
        self.load()
        ...

    def load(self):
        # Load the data from the appropriate directory/file, slow
        ...
```

This gets the rough gist of what I am going for. `Ui_PlotWindow` implements `setupUi`. In practices there `self.settings` stands for a long list of settings variables which can be manipulated by the user. The check on `self.updating` ensures that requests to update the plot which arrive while the plot is currently updating are terminated rather than added to a queue in the worker thread event loop.

Though my code works, I feel like the pattern I am using with the worker thread is a bit strange. Basically ALL of the information needed is in the `PlotWindow` class, but since I want to call one of the methods of the `PlotWindow` class in a separate thread I feel I need a different `QObject` which can live in a different `QThread` to house the slot which will run the expensive method.

It just feels a bit roundabout to have a whole seperate class and object just to call a function which already exists in the first class.. However, I am new to threading applications and perhaps this is a normal pattern and not to be worried about?

I would appreciate any advice for how I might be able to make the flow of this function more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use a different pattern for threading. Instead of the `self.thread =`  and `self.moveToThread` for the worker the worker should simply BE a `QThread`. The thread can be "started" in which case its run method is initiated in a new thread. If a request is made in the main thread to "start" the worker thread again while it is already running nothing will happen. Below is a revision of the above code which implements this pattern.

WARNING: This code is still a bad idea because the plotting involving redrawing GUI objects (the plots). This should not happen in a thread different than the main thread. For posterity I'll state that code in the format in the original question did in fact run but I think that was by luck that the plotting worked in the worker thread. The best pattern would be to have any data loading and processing happen in the worker thread but to then finally emit the data to a plotting method of the main thread to update the GUI with the new data.

```
class PlotWorker(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, plotwindow):
        self.plotwindow = plotwindow
    
    def run(self):
        self.plotwindow.plot()

class PlotWindow(Ui_PlotWindow, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    update_signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.settings = self.settings_lineEdit.text()
        self.worker = PlotWorker(self)
        self.update_settings_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.update_settings)
        self.refresh_timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.refresh_timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.update_settings()
        self.plot()
        self.refresh_time.start(1)


    def update_setting(self):
        self.settings = self.settings_lineEdit.text()
 
    def update(self)
        if self.worker.started():
            print('Already updating, cannot update until previous update complete')
        elif not self.worker.started():
            self.worker.start()

    def plot(self):
        # Plot the data, slow. Uses self.settings
        self.load()
        ...

    def load(self):
        # Load the data from the appropriate directory/file, slow
        ...
```